# Url changed when submit and surrounding issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm newbie in Ruby on rails.

I'm doing CRUD for Articles and have a question: how to keep url and data's form when i create or update a article but it invalid validate?

And if they resolved, how to keep _form.html.erb to use for create and edit view.

I tried some solution in stackoverflow but there are no solution resolved all my problems above.

Here is new article view:

https://ibb.co/bdm4Hxj

You see, url change from /articles

https://ibb.co/wQ6Vxpz

inspect, we see action: /articles, method: post

https://ibb.co/LPJzvLr

and routes in rails:

https://ibb.co/rs1T1PY

_form.html.erb for create and edit view:

```
    <%= form_for @article, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}, local: true do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title, "Title", class: "col-md-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :text, "Text", class: "col-md-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.text_area :text, class: "form-control"%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-4">
      <a class="btn btn-success" href="<%= articles_path %>">Back</a>
      <%= f.submit action_name.capitalize, class: "btn btn-success" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My ArticlesController:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def show
    @article = get_by(:id)
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      flash[:success] = 'Create success!'
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      flash[:warning] = 'Something went wrong!'
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @article = get_by(:id)
  end

  def update
    @article = get_by(:id)

    if @article.update(article_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Update success!'
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      flash[:warning] = 'Update failed!'
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = get_by(:id)
    if @article.destroy
      flash[:success] = 'Delete success!'
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      flash[:warning] = 'Delete failed!'
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end

  def get_by(id)
    Article.find(params[id])
  end
end
```

Thank you and sorry because of my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

Your examples look pretty much what comes out of a scaffold, which is not too bad a start when learning how things can work (`rails g scaffold article`).

The relevant controller and views are then set up to do exactly what you are asking for: The controller holds a local variable (`@article`) ready for the view (ultimately `_form.erb`), whether or not the objects data is valid.

I wonder: What exactly happens? When you save with invalid data, the form should show up with the invalid data still in place. If you compare your form with the one that is created by the `scaffold`, you will notice that some output regarding validation errors is missing in your example. Try to add it, or start from scratch to see how it looks like.

When the data is valid and you still want the controller to show the user the form after hitting save, instead of `redirect_to ...` just `render :edit`.

Comment: When i submit, because of action in form will go to a url other what call method create in controller. So, url will change. I dont want it happens. but if i change action in form, and add something in new method to check cases happens(invalid and valid data), i can't use _form.html.erb for create and edit view both. It's all problem!

Comment: Not sure if I understand you. When you use the scaffolded controller and view, _form will be used for `edit`. If you replace `redirect_to articles_path` (Controller#create) with `render :edit` the URL should still be the same and you will see the form after creation.
Maybe you can explain your expected behaviour with some text like "In Form for new -> click save -> when valid: see form, when invalid see form with errors"...

Comment: Oh! Yep!  Because this is my first time i ask something on the stackoverflow, i get some mistake. Everything went as follows: The form use form_for @article, and when i inspect my web, it displayed: action:'articles/' method="post". When we use render, it will call template, not action. so url will is 'articles/' when i clicked on button submit whatever happened after that . There is a irrational url. The website stay in create article after invalid validate. So, url must be 'articles/new'

Comment: Can you add this information to your main question up here on Stackoverflow, for others to see? Thanks.

Comment: Yep. I updated more details, you can see images above in the article.